# can download zip file from one computer but not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, download

I've got a rails 4.0.5 app that creates a zip file and then sends it to the user via send_file.  Per the api docs, "disposition" is "attachment" by default, the environment is configured to use `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"` for apache, and apache is configured to recognize this in the vhost.

The problem is that I can download these attachments properly from my home or work network, but clients in another state are receiving zero-byte attachments.  They claim there is no firewall interfering with .zip files.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Does your code work right for other kinds of files? Does it work right with, say, an inlined jpg file? Can you reproduce the problem locally using a private browser window, or using a proxy? Are you and your clients in the production environment?

Comment: What user-agents are your clients using? Are you setting `mime-type` correctly? Do you need to set the `content-disposition` header?

Comment: We're both using chrome and safari on mac, the mime-type is being set the same for both of us.